# SQL insert query loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello so i am doing this school assigment where i have make a comment system corresponding to the post ID and i know that it looping three times but i gave it the post id. And i know that the postID is changeing all the time. i just have no idea how to fix this bug any ideas?

```
<?php require_once("menu.php");
$connection = connectToMySQL();

$selectPostQuery = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `tblposts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$selectPostQuery)
    or die("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $postid = $row['ID'];

        if (!empty($_POST['comment']) ) #To insert new comments in the database
        {
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            $userid = $_SESSION['userID'];
            $insertCommentQuery = "INSERT INTO `tblcomments` (`Content`,`UserID`,`PostID`,`Timestamp`) VALUES ('$comment','$userid','$postid',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

            $resultComment = mysqli_query($connection, $insertCommentQuery)
                or die("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
        }

    echo "<div class=\"wrapper\">";
    echo "<div class=\"titlecontainer\">";
    echo "<h1>$row[Title]</h1>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"textcontainer\">";
    echo "<span>$row[Content]</span>";
    echo "</div>";

    if (!empty($row['ImagePath'])) #This will check if there is an path in the textfield
    {
    ?>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="images/<?php echo "$row[ImagePath]"; ?>">
        </div>
<?php
    }
    echo "<div class=\"timestampcontainer\">";
    echo "<b>Date posted :</b>$row[TimeStamp] ";
    echo "<b>Author :</b> Admin";
    echo "</div>";

    #Selecting comments corresponding to the post
    $selectCommentQuery = "SELECT * FROM `tblcomments` LEFT JOIN `tblusers` ON tblcomments.userID = tblusers.ID WHERE tblcomments.PostID ='$postid'";

    $commentResult = mysqli_query($connection,$selectCommentQuery)
        or die ("Error in the query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

    while ($commentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentResult)) 
    {
        echo "<div class=\"commentcontainer\">";
        echo "<div class=\"commentusername\"><h1>Username :$commentRow[Username]</h1></div>";
        echo "<div class=\"commentcontent\">$commentRow[Content]</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"commenttimestamp\">$commentRow[Timestamp]</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }


    if (!empty($_SESSION['userID']) ) 
    {
        echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\" class=\"post-frm\">";
        echo "<label>New Comment</label>";
        echo "<textarea id=\"comment\" name=\"comment\"> </textarea>";
        echo "<input id=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" name =\"submit\" class=\"button\"/>" ;
        echo "</form>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br /> <br /><br />"; 
}
```

require_once("footer.php") ?>

Comment: Just to point it out, you haven't actually posed a question.

Comment: its just very akward to explain its just entering a comment to every each post not to the one that i typed in the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's exactly what your script does. It queries all posts, loops through them, and then performs an insert for all of them. To fix this, store the id of the post in the comment form. When you post the form, insert just a single comment and use the id in the form.

That could look something like this:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('postid', $_POST))
{
  $postid = $_POST['postid'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];

  // Perform a single insert here, and use $postid and $comment.
}

// Then, start rendering the page:

require_once(menu.php);
$connection = connectToMySQL();

$selectPostQuery = SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `tblposts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER BY id DESC;

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$selectPostQuery)
    or die(Error in the query: . mysqli_error($connection));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
  $postid = $row['ID'];
  // Render the post itself here.
?>
  <div class="wrapper">;
  <div class="titlecontainer">;
  <h1><?=$row['Title']?></h1>;
  </div>;
  <div class="textcontainer">;
  <span><?=$row['Content']?></span>;
  </div>; 
<?php
  // Render a comment form for each post (is that what you did?)
  if (!empty($_SESSION['userID']) ) 
  {?>
  <form method=POST action= class=post-frm>
    <label>New Comment</label>
    <textarea id=comment name=comment></textarea>
    <input type=hidden name=postid value=<?=$postid?>/>
    <input id=submit type=submit name =submit class=button/>
  </form>    
  <?}
}
```

Most of your code is the same, only the processing of the post data is now done before the loop.

Otherwise, I just fixed some small syntactic things (and maybe introduced new ones, I haven't tested it).

Also, I took the HTML out of echoes. It's a matter of taste, of course, but experience has taught me that big chunks of HTML in echo statements isn't very readable or maintainable. Rather just close the PHP tags, output the raw HTML and echo only the variables in it. You can use the short notation for that: `<?= $value ?>`, which basically means `<?php echo $value ?>`.

Comment: thank you i will test it out whe i get home and yes i was going to fix that thx for the tip and for the quick response !